# Telling the Truth Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Sally just purchased a lie detector which she wants to try out on her friends.
>
> Sally read online that the test will come back positive 80% of the time the person is lying and will come back positive 20% of the time when the person is telling the truth.
>
> She tests it on three of her friends, Mark who lies 40% of the time, Kathleen who lies 60% of the time and Dylan who lies 10% of the time.
>
> What's the probability that the lie detector shows a positive test on one person and that person was Mark?

$(.8*.4)(1-(.8*.6))(1-(.8*.1)=(.32)(.52)(.92)=.153088$ so 15.3%.  Should I have done a different thing for this?

Comment: Your answer is incorrect as you only consider getting this result when it was true. You don't consider the case where this result is produced from the test but in fact was a false positive

Comment: @WaveX That is not the only error

Comment: @Henry I'm aware that there are calculation mistakes in the OPs attempt as well but I believe this is the core mental mistake that was enacted

Answer (score 1):

Not quite, as a positive test may correctly identify a lie or incorrectly identify a truth. A negative result may incorrectly identify a lie or correctly identify a truth. Instead try:

- The probability of a positive result from Mark is $0.8 \times 0.4 + 0.2 \times 0.6=0.44$
- The probability of a negative result from Kathleen is $0.2 \times 0.6 + 0.8 \times 0.4=0.44$
- The probability of a negative result from Dylan is $0.2 \times 0.1 + 0.8 \times 0.9=0.74$

and multiply these together

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote by $+$ the event that the test is positive on the person we're testing.

For Mark this is $P(+)=P(+| \text{ m lies})P(\text{mark lies}) + P(+|\text{mark truthful})P(\text{mark truthful}) = 0.8 \times 0.4 + 0.2 \times 0.6$

Similarly compute those chances for the others, but for negative tests (take their complement as $P(-)=1-P(+)$, and finally multiply those.